# Tabbing within a table cell

Tags: tables, tabbing

This is a MWE but it will not work however would give the idea of what I am doing.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage{myPackage}
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{12cm}p{1.5cm}}
१.१.१  &  वृद्धिः\textsuperscript{१/१} आत्\textsuperscript{१/१} ऐच्\textsuperscript{१/१}  &  3\\
& आत् ऐच् वृद्धिः सञ्ज्ञा स्युः &  \\
१.१.२  &  अत्\textsuperscript{१/१}  एङ्\textsuperscript{१/१} गुणः\textsuperscript{१/१}  & 3 \\
& अत् एङ् गुणः  सञ्ज्ञा स्युः & \\
\end{longtable}
```

[image: table_tabbing]
As shown in the attached image, I want every other line to be tabbed to the right. I tried to put 4 columns and offset the text by one column but that did not give me good result. Is tabbing possible within a table?

Top image is the output I am getting and the bottom image is the desired output.

Comment: Insert `\quad` (or perhaps `\qquad` which is twice a `\quad`) just before the lines you want indented. That should do it. If you want a bigger space, you could define `\def\qqquad{\hskip3em\relax}` and use `\qqquad` (and/or replace `3em` with whatever you like).

Comment: @ Werner - `\qquad` it did the trick. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inserts a horizontal space at the beginning of the lines you want indented:

[image]

In the code below I have provided a MWE that illustrates the problem and the second one is the one with the horizontal space inserted.  You can change the definition of `\MyIndent` to control the amount of space that is inserted.

### Code

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{6cm}p{1.5cm}}
   text & some more text & 3\\
        & text           &  \\
   text & some more text & 3\\
        & text           &  \\
\end{longtable}
%
\newcommand*{\MyIndent}{\hspace*{0.5cm}}%
\begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{6cm}p{1.5cm}}
   text & some more text       & 3\\
        & \MyIndent text &  \\
   text & some more text       & 3\\
        & \MyIndent text &  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```